Flutter scroll to top after statusbar tap for selected tab in bottom navigation
In Flutter, we can scroll to the top after tapping the status bar by passing the PrimaryScrollController from the root Scaffold to the ScrollView. However, my app has a bottom navigation with 4 tabs, each containing a ScrollView. When I tap the status bar, all 4 tabs scroll to the top, but I only want the currently selected tab to scroll.
Following this thread, it seems like there’s no official way to do it
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/85603#issuecomment-876798161
Are there any workarounds or alternative ways to scroll only the selected tab to the top after tapping the status bar?

can you share what you have trued so far?

I encountered the same problem a while ago and came up with my own solution. It may not be exactly what you're looking for, but it worked perfectly for me.
I use only a list of offsets, which I store the offset of each page being showed
Here is the example app code for you to test if you want:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;

  final ScrollController scrollController = ScrollController();
  List<double> offsets = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    // Number of options in the bottomNavigationBar
    offsets.addAll([0, 0, 0]);
    super.initState();
  }

  final List<Widget> _pages = [
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: List.generate(
            20, (index) => ListTile(title: Text('Home Item $index'))),
      ),
    ),
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: List.generate(
            20, (index) => ListTile(title: Text('Search Item $index'))),
      ),
    ),
    SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Column(
        children: List.generate(
            20, (index) => ListTile(title: Text('Profile Item $index'))),
      ),
    ),
  ];

  void _scrollToTop() {
    scrollController.jumpTo(0);
  }

  void _onTabTapped(int index) {
    // Select the offset for the selected page
    offsets[_currentIndex] = scrollController.offset;
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
      scrollController.jumpTo(offsets[index]);
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return PrimaryScrollController(
      controller: scrollController,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('BottomNavigationBar + Scroll'),
        ),
        body: _pages[_currentIndex],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: _currentIndex,
          onTap: _onTabTapped,
          items: [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              label: 'Search',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.person),
              label: 'Profile',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        floatingActionButton: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: [
            FloatingActionButton(
              onPressed: _scrollToTop,
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
              tooltip: 'Scroll to Top',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

